# Finding the last used cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

Anyone knows how to check if the cell contains a data using VBScript? Because of what I have seen, it's a bit differrent from VBA. I have tried this code but is not working:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\test.xlsx")
Set user = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
logname = user.Username

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

If Hour(Now) >= 1 And Hour(Now) =< 11 Then
    WScript.Echo "Good Morning"
    WScript.Echo "Log Record is:", Time, Date

    lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Cells(lastrow+1, 1).Value = logname
End If
```

After checking if the row contains a data, the code will insert data to the next row that doesn't contain a data. We'll say: if `CELL A1` has a data, then `CELL A2` is empty, then the data to be inserted will be inserted in `CELL A2`.

Please note that I'm working on [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), not [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

Comment: VBS will not recognize Excel constants. In this case `xlDown`. You need to use the enumeration for this, which can be found in the Object Browser in the VBE, by searching on the constant `xlDown` or any other constant. In this case the enumeration is `-4121`. You also may be better served using `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row` since, as written, the code will return the last row in the spreadsheet if only cell A1 has data or column A is empty.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman I have updated my code above and is not working well. It is just updating the value of the cell .Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`UsedRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) property:

```
Set ws = objExcel.ActiveSheet

With ws.UsedRange
  nextrow = .Row + .Rows.Count
End With

Set cell = ws.Cells(nextrow, 1).Range("A1")

cell.Value = logname
```

Comment: the code works as the same as mine. It is not inserting to the next row that doesn't contain a data. This code is just replacing the content of the row. And is not also inserting data to the row.Thanks!

Comment: @ramedju The code I posted doesn't replace anything. It merely selects the bottom right cell of the used range. If you need the row below that: simply don't subtract 1 when calculating `lastrow`.

Comment: So, after identifying that the cell is empty, how can I insert data to the empty cell? Thanks!

Comment: Umm... you assign the data as the cell's value? `cell.Value = data`

Comment: Why is it that inserts data staring from Column C? I'm sorry coz I'm really new to this, I want the data to be inserted in Column A. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously, if you want to insert data in the *first* column you'd use the number of the *first* column (1) instead of calculating the number of the *last* column.